# Reading XML nodes in loop in PHP script to make copy results in duplicates

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

In this php script I read the `<URLS>` node in the xml file to make a backup copy of that node.  The copy ends up with duplicates. There are extra `<URL>` nodes added to the `<URLS>` node.  I want to understand why this happens. Here are the PHP script and the XML file.

PHP Script

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

function backup_urls( $nodeid ) { 

$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$dom->load('communities.xml'); 

$dom->formatOutput = true;  
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true; 

// get document element   

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$nodes = $xpath->query("//COMMUNITY[@ID='$nodeid']");  

if ($nodes->length) { 

   $node = $nodes->item(0);  

   $xurls = $xpath->query("//COMMUNITY[@ID='$nodeid']/URLS"); 

   if ($xurls->length) { 
     $xurle = $xpath->query("//COMMUNITY[@ID='$nodeid']/URLS_BACKUP"); 
    echo "backup length: ".$xurle->length; 
    if ($xurle->length) $node->removeChild($xurle->item(0)); 

    $xurlb = $dom->createElement("URLS_BACKUP");  
    $node->appendChild($xurlb); 

    $urldelete = $xurls->item(0); 

    $xurll = $urldelete->getElementsByTagName ("URL"); 

    foreach($xurll as $url) 
    {  
      $urlid = $url->getAttribute('ID'); 
      $xurl = $dom->createElement("URL"); 
      $xurl->setAttribute("ID", $urlid); 
      $xurlb->appendChild($xurl); 

      $name = $url->getElementsByTagName("NAME")->item(0)->nodeValue; 
      $xuname     = $dom->createElement("NAME"); 
      $xunameText = $dom->createTextNode($name); 
      $xuname->appendChild($xunameText); 
      $xurl->appendChild($xuname); 

      $urllink = $url->getElementsByTagName("URLC")->item(0)->nodeValue; 
      $xulink     = $dom->createElement("URLC"); 
      $xulinkText = $dom->createTextNode($urllink);   
      $xulink->appendChild($xulinkText);  
      $xurl->appendChild($xulink);  

      echo "urlid: ".$urlid." name: ".$name." link: ".$urllink; 
    } 

    $node->removeChild($urldelete); 

   } 

} 

$dom->save('communities.xml'); 
} 

echo backup_urls(trim($_REQUEST['nodeid']));
```

XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
    <COMMUNITIES> 
    <COMMUNITY ID="c001"> 
      <NAME>Town Services</NAME>  
      <TOP>41</TOP>  
      <LEFT>52</LEFT>  
      <WIDTH>200</WIDTH>  
      <HEIGHT>300</HEIGHT>  
      <URLS> 
          <URL ID="U001"> 
              <NAME>Google.com</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.google.com</URLC> 
          </URL> 
          <URL ID="U002"> 
              <NAME>Bing.com</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.bing.com</URLC> 
          </URL> 
          <URL ID="U003"> 
              <NAME>Yahoo.com</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.yahoo.com</URLC> 
          </URL> 
          <URL ID="U004"> 
              <NAME>Aol.com</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.aol.com</URLC> 
          </URL> 
      </URLS>  
      </COMMUNITY> 
    <COMMUNITY ID="c002"> 
      <NAME>Local Stores</NAME>  
      <TOP>27</TOP>  
      <LEFT>270</LEFT>  
      <WIDTH>200</WIDTH>  
      <HEIGHT>150</HEIGHT>  
      <URLS> 
          <URL ID="U001"> 
              <NAME>Walgreens</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.walgreens.com</URLC> 
          </URL> 
          <URL ID="U002"> 
              <NAME>Bing.com</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.bing.com</URLC> 
          </URL> 
          <URL ID="U003"> 
              <NAME>Yahoo.com</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.yahoo.com</URLC> 
          </URL> 
      </URLS>  
      </COMMUNITY> 
    <COMMUNITY ID="c003"> 
      <NAME>Attractions</NAME>  
      <TOP>50</TOP>  
      <LEFT>490</LEFT>  
      <WIDTH>200</WIDTH>  
      <HEIGHT>300</HEIGHT>  
      <URLS> 
          <URL ID="U001"> 
              <NAME>Museum</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.mfa.org</URLC> 
          </URL> 
          <URL ID="U002"> 
              <NAME>Park</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.bing.com</URLC> 
          </URL> 
      </URLS>  
      </COMMUNITY> 


    <COMMUNITY ID="c006"> 
      <NAME>Travel</NAME>  
      <TOP>370</TOP>  
      <LEFT>490</LEFT>  
      <WIDTH>200</WIDTH>  
      <HEIGHT>200</HEIGHT>  
      <URLS> 
          <URL ID="U001"> 
              <NAME>Southwest</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.mfa.org</URLC> 
          </URL> 
          <URL ID="U002"> 
              <NAME>Northwest</NAME> 
              <URLC>http://www.bing.com</URLC> 
          </URL> 
      </URLS>  
      </COMMUNITY> 
    <COMMUNITY ID="c000010"> 
      <NAME>New000010</NAME> 
      <TOP>372</TOP> 
      <LEFT>54</LEFT> 
      <WIDTH>200</WIDTH> 
      <HEIGHT>150</HEIGHT> 
      <URLS> 
        <URL ID="u000038"> 
        <NAME>Google.com</NAME> 
        <URLC>http://google.com</URLC></URL> 
      </URLS> 
    </COMMUNITY> 
    <COMMUNITY ID="c000011"> 
      <NAME>N000011</NAME> 
      <TOP>370</TOP> 
      <LEFT>295</LEFT> 
      <WIDTH>150</WIDTH> 
      <HEIGHT>150</HEIGHT> 
      <URLS> 
        <URL ID="u000040"> 
          <NAME>AOL.com</NAME> 
          <URLC>http://www.aol.com</URLC> 
        </URL> 
      </URLS> 
    </COMMUNITY> 
    <COMMUNITY ID="c000002"> 
      <NAME>ID000002</NAME> 
      <TOP>192</TOP> 
      <LEFT>297</LEFT> 
      <WIDTH>150</WIDTH> 
      <HEIGHT>150</HEIGHT> 
      <URLS> 
        <URL ID="u000002"> 
          <NAME>Facebook.com</NAME> 
          <URLC>http://www.facebook.com</URLC> 
        </URL> 
      </URLS> 
    </COMMUNITY> 
</COMMUNITIES>
```

Comment: Which nodes are duplicated? Is it just the parent (community) nodes or all nodes?

Comment: @Clive The node that I want to copy and where there are duplicates is the <URLS> node.  When I read the <URL> nodes under <URLS> there are extra <URL> nodes added.